# Django formset fails date validation with valid date

Tags: django, django-forms, django-2.0

I'm running into a date validation error with use of a django formset.   I do not get the same validation error when I `formset.is_valid()`.  The problem I'm experiencing is that the form `is_valid` check fails, only with the view and template use (not in the shell) specifically when using a date in the form of "March 20 2018" whereas it always passes with "2018-03-20".

Also I can verify the data is in the `request.POST` but the invalid `due_date` key is missing from self.cleaned_data when I look for it in the form's clean method.  Perhaps that's normal given the invalid key but I would expect that to occur *after* the clean, not before, if at all.  Feels like maybe its a django bug, I'm on django 2.0.2

Here's a summary of construction, its pretty vanilla:

```
# models.py
class Schedule(models.Model):
    # ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=choices.NOT_STARTED, choices=choices.SCHEDULE_STATUSES)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ...

# forms.py
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Schedule
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'status', 'due_date']

# views.py
def line_schedules_edit(request, line_slug):
    line = get_object_or_404(models.Line, slug=line_slug)
    queryset = line.schedules.all()

    ScheduleFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Schedule, form=forms.ScheduleForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        schedules_formset = ScheduleFormSet(request.POST)

        if schedules_formset.is_valid():
            schedules_formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('products:line-schedules-edit',
                                                kwargs={'line_slug': line_slug}))
    else:
        schedules_formset = ScheduleFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    context = {
        'line': line,
        'formset': schedules_formset
    }

    return render(request, 'line-schedules-edit.html', context)


# template
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% csrf_token %}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}{{ hidden }}{% endfor %}
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

With this structure I continually get an error of invalid date for due date when I use "March 3 2018" whereas if I provide a form input of "2018-03-18" in the browser, it works.  Yet in a shell I'm able to verify that *both* date formats work:

```
In [35]: POST = {
   'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
   'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
   'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '2',
   'form-0-name': 'Test',
   'form-0-status': 'Not started',
   'form-0-due_date': '2018-03-20',
   'form-1-name': 'Test',
   'form-1-status': 'Not started',
   'form-1-due_date': 'March 20, 2018'
}

In [36]: qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
         qdict.update(POST)
         formset = ScheduleFormSet(qdict)

In [37]: formset.is_valid()
Out[37]: True
```

Why does the view and template fail the validation and why is the `due_date` key missing in the form's clean method?

Comment: re: the timing of the data and the `clean` method, `Form.clean` runs after the specific field validations have run, and if the field value is considered invalid at that point, it will be removed from `cleaned_data`. Later in the flow, it won't be present when you hit the `clean` method. I don't know why it's failing validation, though.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed to do was to provide input formats to pre-process the format before its sent off to the model.  It must have been built-in model validation failing since it cannot store it in the form of "March 2 2018".

Using `input_formats` in the form, we can cast it to the desired format before the model processes it:

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Schedule
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'status', 'due_date']

    due_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d %B, %Y'),
                               input_formats=('%d %B, %Y',),
                               required=False)
```